# Getting the response from HttpKernel for an url, parallelized

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, amphp

I am using https://github.com/JosephSilber/page-cache to cache pages. To prepare pages beforehand (about 100,000), I used to run 8 http requests in parallel via GuzzleHttp. It worked, but was pretty slow, because of the overhead.

I am looking for a way to process an instance of `Illuminate\Http\Request` directly via the app instance, preventing a real http request. I noticed, that this is much faster. However, parallelizing this with https://github.com/amphp/parallel-functions poses some problems.

The basic code is this:

```
    wait(parallelMap($urlChunks->all(), function($urls) {
            foreach($urls as $url) {
                //handle the request
            }
        }, $pool));
```

I tried several variants for handling the request.

1.

```
$request = \Illuminate\Http\Request::create($url, 'GET');
$response = app()->handle($request);
```

In this case `app()` returns an instance of `Illuminate\Container\Container`, not an instance of app. So it does not have the method `handle()`and so on.

2.

```
$request = \Illuminate\Http\Request::create($url, 'GET');
$response = $app->handle($request);
```

Only difference here: The variable `$app` was injected into the closure. Its value is the correct return value from `app()` called outside the closure. It is the application, but amp fails, because the PDO connections contained in the Application instance can not be serialized.

3.

```
$request = \Illuminate\Http\Request::create($url, 'GET');
$app = require __DIR__.'/../../../bootstrap/app.php';
$app->handle($request);
```

This works for a short while. But with each instantiation of the app, one or two mysql connections start to linger around in status "Sleep". They only get closed, when the script ends. **Important: This does not have to do with parallelization.** I actually tried the same with a sequential loop and noticed the same effect. This looks like an error in the framework to me, because one should expect, that the Application instance closes all connections, when it is destroyed. Or can I do this manually? This would be one way to get this thing to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The third version is my recommended way to do it. Resources in PHP are usually cleaned up when PHP exists, but that doesn't work for long running applications. To change that, I'd file an issue in the Laravel repository or whatever is creating that database connection.

Comment: Actually, it is not a long running application. Application gets started, handles the url and the script ends. Less than a second runtime. I thought, that the container concept of Laravel would easily allow starting an app and ending it any number of times, without issues.